# add sales order information to an invoice in openerp RML

Tags: python, odoo, rml

In my sales order I have a customer reference number that needs to be referenced in my customer invoice, The invoice uses the source document to search for it's related sales order, then searches the sales records. I've the following in my RML:

```
[[o.getcustomerPO(origin) or 'No associated PO' ]]
```

and this in my parser:

```
    def getcustomerPO(self,so_num):
context = {}
saleorder = self.pool.get('sale.order')
sale_oID = saleorder.search(self.cr, self.uid,[('name','=','so_num')],context=context)
customerPO = saleorder.browse(self.cr, self.uid, sale_oID, context=context)
return customerPO
```

But no dice.

I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether You update local context with that function or not by this:

```
self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'getcustomerPO': self.getcustomerPO,
        })
```

In rml, it should be like this:

```
[[ getcustomerPO(origin) or 'No associated PO' ]]
```

One more thing, In this report, the boolean is ticked for 'Reload from Attachment'. It means that Second time when you will print the report, it will come up with the previous report. So, you also need to un-tick that boolean from report.xml file by adding this attribute:

```
attachment_use="True"
```

Thanks.

Comment: The attachment_use="true" is fine, since it should only be printed once, and if it is changed, they can delete the attached invoice to update to the newest one.
I'm not sure where I should put self.localcontext.update.

Comment: edit: nvr mind on that last comment, I just wasn't looking...
Still no luck though

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[[getcustomerPO(o.origin) or 'No associated PO' ]]
```

Comment: please check whether your function gets the calls. Please check it by adding print statement in __init__ function.

Comment: I have the following as init function
'code' class account_invoice(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(account_invoice, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        print 'localcontext'
  self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
   'getcustomerPO': self.getcustomerPO,
        })

Comment: But I receive no print statement

Comment: i think you have done wrong..please show us your xml code for calling your new report and how you call your report parser.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report
            auto="False"
            id="account.account_invoices"
            model="account.invoice"
            name="account.invoice.kaertech"
            rml="kaertech_report_account/report/kaertech_invoice.rml"
            string="Invoices"
            attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
            usage="default"
            multi="True"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
call parser:
[[getcustomerPO(o) or 'No associated PO' ]]

Comment: what you have given to call your report parser in ypur python code ? for example: report_sxw.report_sxw('report.account.account.balance', 'account.account', 'addons/account/report/account_balance.rml', parser=account_balance, header="internal")

Comment: report_sxw.report_sxw(
    'report.account.invoice.kaertech',
    'account.invoice',
    'addons/kaertech_report_account/report/account_print_invoice.rml',
    parser=account_invoice
)

Comment: please check whether you have added these file in your openerp and init python files of your module. I cant find any other issue

Comment: init:
import invoice
import report

Comment: have you added your xml file path in __openerp__.py?

Comment: 'images' : [],
    'init_xml': [],
    'depends' : [],
    'update_xml': ['account_report.xml'],
    'demo_xml': [],
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
 'auto_install': False,
}